# I have EXC_BAD_ACCESS when call pjsua_destroy() function in PJSIP

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

I have an IOS VOIP application, using PJSIP library. The problem is when I make outbounding call and after it I call pjsua_destroy() function it always crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The last string in logs is:

```
pjsua_media.c  .Shutting down media..
```

It seems like media is not deallocated properly or smth like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable video call before making audio call,

`//--- Disable video call before make call ------`

```
pjsua_call_setting callSettings;
pjsua_call_setting_default(&callSettings);
callSettings.vid_cnt = 0;

status = pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &pj_uri, &callSettings, NULL, NULL, call_id);
```